# Dynamic rendering in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following array:

```
const elements = [
    {
        title: "foo"
        section: <div>Foo <button onClick={sayHello}>Greet</button></div>
    },
    {
        title: "bar"
        section: <div>Bar <button onClick={sayHello}>Greet</button></div>
    }
];
```

I want to render the component with something like:

```
const someSections = this.state.elements.map((item, i) => (
    <div key={i}>
    {item.section}
    </div>
));

...

render(){
    return (
        ...
        <div>
            {someSections}
        </div>
    )
}
```

But I can't render them. The error is:

`Uncaught Error: objects are not valid as a React child`

Comment: item.section, not link.section in your map :D

Comment: Your data really shouldn't contain HTML, only the templates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the working solution:

```js
const data = [
    {
        title: "foo",
        section: <div>Foo <button>Greet</button></div>
    },
    {
        title: "bar",
        section: <div>Bar <button>Greet</button></div>
    }
]


class App extends React.Component{
  render(){
     return(
        <div>
          {
              data.map((item,i)=>{
                  return <div key={i}>{item.section}</div>
              })
          }
        </div>
     )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App/>,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

normally you would do something like this.

```
render(){
    let someSections = this.state.elements.map((item, i) => (
        <div key={i}>
            {item.section}
        </div>
    ));

    return (
        <div>
            {someSections}
        </div>
    )
}
```